# Need to find the correct Hex Value for a Little Endian system

Tags: sqlite, hex, blob, endianness

I am trying to determine what the correct value would be to input a number into an SQli query. I have been able to deduce (I believe) that the database is using little endian by playing with the hex values. For example:

To modify a value to 255, I am having to use 00000000FF000000.
For values 1-255 this has been fine, it has worked every time.

My question is, for the values 265 and 275, which in hex is converted to 109 and 113, how would I position the numbers within this 16 digit series?

0000000010900000 does not work and returns a value of 36880
Likewise, shifting the 109 to the left instead, returns a value of 9

I am using http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ to try and determine the correct value, using the little endian boxes.

Comment: I found it, sorry for the post. I still dont understand why 265 is 901000 and 275 is 1301000 though... I would have guessed 311000 for the second one...

Comment: SQLite's internal endianness does not show up in SQL. Where exactly are you using 16 hex digits?

Comment: Modifying stats in a database, The values listed are in 16 digit hex, when I tried using smaller form it would not function correctly, when I used big endian it was the wrong value.

Comment: What stats? SQLite does not even have a 16-digit data type; is this a string, or a blob?

Comment: blob (extra stuff to meet 15char limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value string seem to be a structure or an array consisting of 16-bit values in little-endian format.

You can see this by examining the values this way:

for example:

```
00000000FF000000
```

can be broken down into 16-bit values:

```
0000 0000 FF00 0000
```

And when byte-order for 0xff00 is swapped we get 0xff, ie. 255.

For this value:

```
0000000010900000
```

we get:

```
0000 0000 1090 0000
```

When byte-order is swapped to `0x9010` we get `36880`, as in the result.

You don't state why there is a 16-char limit that needs to be fulfilled, but in general - this seem to be part of a *structure* or an 16-bit array rather than a 64-bit value (which is normally represented by 8 bytes, or 16 chars) but since the value then should have been at either end it is likely not a 64-bit value.

This is normally not something one can guess automatically and would require you know the structure or array definition (talking about binary arrays). One can of course use a pattern to find values matching a range using various positions, width and byte-order, but I cannot see you would benefit in this case compared to finding out the structure/array format (above I *guess* 4x 16-bit values, but it could just as well have been 1x32-bit, 1x16-bit and 2x8-bit etc.).

> My question is, for the values 265 and 275, which in hex is converted to 109 and 113, how would I position the numbers within this 16 digit series?

To fill the binary array you would place them at position 4 (0-base) as 16-bit values in little-endian order.

You can use the DataView for this as it has built-in support for endianess.

## Example

Converting value 275 and placing it in the array with correct endianess and position:

```js
var arr = new Uint8Array(8);
var view = new DataView(arr.buffer);

// set value in correct byte-order and position
view.setUint16(4, 275, true);  // pos, value, little-endian

// show result (convert to hex-string)
for (var str = "", i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) str += pad(arr[i].toString(16));
  
console.log(str);

function pad(s) {return s.length < 2 ? "0"+s : s}; // helper: pads to format 0x00
```

This produces the string:

```
0000000013010000
```

Which if we use the same method as earlier becomes:

```
0000 0000 1301 0000
```

And then byte-order swap `0x1301` it becomes `0x0113`, or `275` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Blobs are just an array of bytes; the database does not modify their contents or their order in any way.

The endianness (or any other way in which the bytes are to be interpreted) is determined only by the application that writes and reads the blob.